# Hidden variables are getting sent in the query string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a form in Shopify. On click of a button, I call a JavaScript function that takes some of the fields, sets them in hidden variables and then submits the form...here are some snippets.

```
<input type="button" name="next" onclick="javascript:validate(); return false;" class="btn" value="Next">

function validate(){ 
 var xv  = $( "#x" ).val();
 var hd = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "hx[aa]").attr("id", "hx[aa]").val("xv");
 $('#myForm').append(hd);
 $("#myForm").submit();
}
```

The form method is set to post but when the submit happens, i can see the `hx[aa]` in the query string.

`?hx[aa]=12345`

I have a feeling that this has nothing to do with Shopify but something else that I am missing on. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, because this is exactly how it should work?!

Comment: @AlonEitan `hidden` fields will be submitted, yes. But they respect the defined method, which is - according to OP - `post` and therefor it should not be added to the query string.

Comment: You can use this `var hd = $("<input>", {"type":"hidden","name":hx[aa],"id":hx[aa],"value":"xv"});` - quote the hx[aa] if that is the actual name. It is easier to validate

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you form has `method` attribute with value that is equal to `post`

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">
  <input type="button" name="next" onclick="javascript:validate(); return false;" class="btn" value="Next">
</form>
```